# Notepad++ double-click behavior with quotes

Tags: notepad++, text-editors

So up until recently if I double-clicked something in Notepad++ like this: `'something'` or `"something_else"` the auto-select would be inside the quotes so that just the string itself was selected. Today, for some reason, a setting has change so that the auto-selection is ignoring quotes, but still stopping the selection at any other non alpha-numeric character. So, for instance, `'#something'` ends up selecting `something'` on double-click.

Is this a Notepad++ core update? (I think I updated a few days ago, if I remember right).

If not, does anyone know the setting I have to change to get this back to the way it was and why it may have happened?

Edit: This seems to only be happening on .js files

Comment: It's not due to an update. I'm seeing the same behaviour with 7.2.2. On normal txt files as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem [has been reported in the Notepad++ community](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/13620/double-click-a-word-selects-more-than-that-word).

A working solution seems to be uninstalling Notepad++ and manually reinstalling. When uninstalling you can select to keep your configuration files, one user reports that this does not prevent the reinstallation process from fixing the problem.

Sidenote: Remember to include version numbers, and debug information "menu -> ? -> Debug info..." next time.

Comment: This did not fix it for me.